# How do I return all pages from a rest API request without manually specifying the page number?

Tags: python, json, loops, rest, pagination

I'm retrieving data from a paginated API and converting it to .JSON format and I'd like to retrieve all pages in the response, without having to specify the page number in the URL. The API accepts page number and results per page (max. 250) as inputs.

I understand that the typical solution is to loop through pages using a key that specifies the address of the next page. However, it appears as though this API doesn't include a next page parameter in the output (see example response below). I can only think that the last page (i.e. total pages) parameter could be useful here? How can I scrape all of the pages without specifying the page number?

**My script:**

```
  import requests
  import json

  url = "https://api-v2.pitchbook.com/deals/search?keywords=machine learning accelerator&perPage=250"

  payload={}
  headers = {
      'Authorization': 'PB-Token 1234567'
   }

  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

  data = response.json()

  print(data)
```

**Example response**

{'stats': {'total': 2, 'perPage': 250, 'page': 1, 'lastPage': 1}, 'items': [{'dealId': '98982-
28T', 'companyId': '162120-79', 'companyName': 'companyA'}, {'dealId': '112532-05T',
'companyId': '233527-87', 'companyName': 'companyB'}]}

Answer (score 1):

> without having to specify the page number in the URL

Unless you can pass a page number in the request header, that's not possible. You could pass a very large number to `perPage` parameter, but the server could always have more data, or the client would fail to deserialize large payloads.

> appears as though this API doesn't include a next page parameter in the output

It doesn't need to. You have your current page, and the number of results "per page" . As long as the "total" has not yet been read into your local results, and "last page" is greater than your current "page", you should make a new request for `page+1`